# How to iterate two list in parallel in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin

How do I iterate two lists in Kotlin? I want to assign each value in one list to the equivalent `textview` in another list, like 1 : 1 assignment.

Something like the following allows parallel iteration but it gets executed twice:

```
data class Total(val area : Double)

private fun assign(
    allArea: List<Double>, allTextViews : List<TextView>
) : Total {
    var totalArea = 0.0

    allArea.forEach { double ->
        val value : Double = double
        totalArea += value

        allTextViews.forEach { textView ->
            textView.text = value.toString()
        }
    }
    return Total(totalArea)
}

assign(allStates = listOf(
        a,
        b
    ),
    allTextViews = listOf(
        textView1,
        textView2)
)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to zip two lists:

```
fun main() {
    val list1 = listOf(1,2,3)
    val list2 = listOf(4,5,6)
    list1.zip(list2).forEach {pair -> 
       println(pair.component1() + pair.component2())
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
5
7
9
```

In your case given the `allArea` list and `allTextViews` have the same length, you can zip them and get the pair of which the first component will be of type `Double`, and the second is of type `TextView`

Comment: it will be more readable `{ (a, b) -> 
       println(a + b)
    }`

Comment: This will work the same: `list1.zip(list2) {it1, it2-> println(it1 + it2) }` . As you see, no need for forEach.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the most 'functional programming" way:

```
fun main() {
    val listA = listOf(10, 20, 30)
    val listB = listOf(1,2,3)
    listA.zip(listB) { a, b -> println(a + b) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use **zip** operator them making a pair but make sure they equal sizes.

```
fun main() {
    val listA = listOf("A","B","C")
    val listB = listOf(1,2,3)
    val zippedList = listA.zip(listB)
    //or
    val zippedListIterative = listA.zip(listB, {a, b -> "${a} = ${b}"}).toList()
    println(zippedList)
}
```

you can then have transformation inside the lambda function or take it as list and then iterate over it.