# How to iterate list two items at a time?

Tags: kotlin

Is there some nice Kotlin idiom to efficiently iterate a list two items at a time?

Something like:

```
val items = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four")

items.forEach(2) { item1, item2 ->
   println("$item1 and $item2")    
}
```

and the output would be:

```
one and two
three and four
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do with each pair of items? One possibility would be to `zip` those lists. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452362/how-to-iterate-two-list-in-parallel-in-kotlin)...

Comment: I don't have two lists. Just one. Let's say I just want to print them in pairs :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use [`chunked(2)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html)

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    .chunked(2)
    .forEach { println(it) }
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7]
```

---

If you ensure the number of elements is even, you can access the pairs with named variables:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    .also { require(it.size % 2 == 0) { "Number of elements must be even" } }
    .chunked(2)
    .forEach { (item1, item2) ->
        println("$item1 and $item2")
    }
```

Prints:

```
1 and 2
3 and 4
5 and 6
```

Comment: Is it possible to have access to pairs in odd lists, such that the second parameter is nullable?